# Returning false if variable doesn't exist

Tags: javascript

I have some code structured like this but with a bunch of variables with paths of various depths within dict that may or may not exist:

```
var dict = {
  'test1': 'test',
  'test2': ['testa', 'testb'],
}

var test_path1 = dict['test2']['testa'] ? test_path1: false
var test_path2 = dict['test3']['testz'] ? test_path2: false

console.log(test_path2)
```

Basically my program creates a bunch of arrays that it saves within user_dict depending on user input. Later I need to process dict and check some of the variables to see their values, or whether or not they exist.

I can't even get to that point though, since defining test_path2 returns "cannot read property testz of undefined."

I thought using ? test_path2: false would work, but I still get that same error.

Someone suggested using optional chaining, but that doesn't seem like a good solution since some of my variables are located within 4-5 nested objects/arrays, each of which may or may not exist.

What's the best way to handle this? Is there an error with my syntax or am I approaching the problem the wrong way? All I need is for test_path1 and test_path2 to return false if it doesn't exist.

Comment: If you have option chaining setup in babel you can do: `let arrayItem = arr?.[42];` at each level. If you don't you're going to have a nasty loop checking if each value exists before checking the next.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use some modern javascript features. Try Optional Chaining:

```
var dict = {
  'test1': 'test',
  'test2': { 'testa': 'testb' },
}

var test_path1 = dict['test2']?.['testa'] || false
var test_path2 = dict['test3']?.['testz'] || false

console.log(test_path1, test_path2)
```

Comment: Thank you, this seems to work. If I can ask something else, part of my code involves doing something like if (test_path1 && test_path1.includes('words'));
I'm getting "test_path1.includes is not a function." Is there anyway to handle that?

Comment: I guess I should separate them into separate if statements to avoid it reaching .includes if it doesn't exist? Anyway thanks, marking this answer correct.

Answer (score 1):

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining

optional chaining can and will work even on deep nested objects

to top it off, you can use the nullish coalescing to return a "default" (fale in your case)

```js
var test_path1 = dict['test2']?.['testa'] ?? false
```

this will return the value or false if it is undefined

Comment: So I tried doing that, but even when the value exists it returns false.

var test_path1 = dict?.['test2']?.['testa'] ?? false;
console.log(test_path1);

Comment: That's returning false for me. Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Technobulka posted a similar answer without ?. at the base level, and with || instead of ?? which seems to be working.

Comment: my mistake, it will already return undefined on base level

Comment: about the `||` vs `??`: `||` this will return the right side for any falsy result (null, undefined, empty string, 0) while `??` will only return the right side for null or undefined. and sometimes you want it to return a 0 and/or a empty string

Answer (score 1):

Arguably, the best way to handle this (while keeping legacy compatibility) is using `get` from `lodash`:

```
import { get } from 'lodash';
const result = get(dict, ['test2', 'testa']) || false;
// or
const result = get(dict, 'test2.testa') || false;
```

Note: to only import `get` (and nothing else) from `lodash`, use `lodash-es` instead of `lodash`. In other words, by using `lodash-es` you enable tree-shaking lodash at build step.

or you could simply check each level:

```
const result = dict && dict.test2 && dict.test2.testa || false;
```

If legacy compatibility is not an issue, you could use optional chaining, as suggested in [Noriller's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68249408/1891677).

Answer (score 0):

If you want to write more optimistic code you could also use a try catch at some point in the code.

```js
try {
  return dict.test1.test2
} catch (e) {
  if (e instanceof TypeError)
    return false

  throw e
}
```

This prevents the need for writing code that does null checks.